# Docker and NodeJS: could not connect to the container

Tags: node.js, docker, rest, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize a simple NodeJS API, I've tested it as a standalone and it's working. But after dockerize it I can't connect to the container, in the next image you can see two important facts: the container is permanently restarting and I could not connect to it:

[image]

After try to establish connection using a GET request the container begins to restart and after a minute later is up for short seconds.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-buster-slim

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /opt/myapps/noderest01

COPY package.json /opt/myapps/noderest01/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /opt/myapps/noderest01/package-lock.json
RUN npm ci

COPY . /opt/myapps/noderest01

EXPOSE 3005

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

And this my yaml file:

```
services:
  rest01:
    container_name: rest01
    ports:
      - "3005:3005"
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
      - rest01:/opt/myapps/noderest01
      - rest01nmodules:/opt/myapps/noderest01/node_modules
    networks:
      - node-rest01
volumes:
  rest01:
  rest01nmodules:  
networks:
  node-rest01:
```

I used this command to create the image: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up -d`

Surely, I need to update my yaml or dockerfile to fix this, I've been searching for a while but I can't find the origin of the problem, so I want to ask for your advises how to fix and update my docker's files and connect to the container, if you have any suggestions please let me know.

Best.

Comment: If you remove the `-d` it should show the logs for the process in the same terminal. Anything show up there of note?

Comment: yes, that did the trick!, I had a typo in my app.js, fix it and then rebuilt the container, now everything is working. THX